# Handling bad ifstream

Tags: c++, file, coding-style, ifstream

if in a C++ program, im reading in files, and one of them is not read correctly for some reason, and was not opened properly, is it a good idea to close the `fstream`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fstream will automatically close when you go out of scope in C++. I don't see why you would ever need to manually close fstream in C++/

Answer (score 2):

you can skip all of that by just checking to see if the file was loaded properly..

```
ifstream file(_path);
if(file.good()) {
    //do anything you want to the file  
}
```

nb. *except in cases like these as a good habit you should always close files after you are finished with them.*